# Can CREATE DATABASE reliably override lc_monetary?

Tags: postgresql

Postgres has a MONEY data type. According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html this is a fixed point decimal data type, with the scale being determined by a variable called `lc_monetary`.

Most of the discussion about this variable e.g. https://pgpedia.info/l/lc_monetary.html talks in terms of it being set by a program called `initdb`.

As an application programmer, I can reasonably assume that I'm the one who gets to issue the `CREATE DATABASE` command. But I might not be the one who gets to run `initdb`. Someone else might have already done that by the time my code starts running, and I don't have a way to control what they did with it.

It would be nice if there was a way to override that variable at the time of `CREATE DATABASE`. But it's not on the list of options at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html

On the other hand, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html suggest it might be. (Though it only talks in terms of formatting of money amounts. Fixed point also needs to adjust the arithmetic. But maybe that's just a slight imprecision in the wording.)

Is it in fact possible for `CREATE DATABASE` to override `lc_monetary` such that this will always work correctly, irrespective of what was done with `initdb`?

Comment: rewrite the code for `CREATE DATABASE` ? (My guess is that it's here: https://doxygen.postgresql.org/createdb_8c.html )

Comment: As you can see in the example you mention, you can even change this setting during your database transaction. My humble opinion: Avoid this data type like the plague, don't use it.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Now that is an interesting perspective! You think this datatype should be avoided like the plague? Just because of the possibility of `lc_monetary` accidentally being set to the wrong value, or are there other reasons?

Comment: From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html: *The other locale settings lc_messages, lc_monetary, lc_numeric, and lc_time are not fixed per database and are not set by this command. If you want to make them the default for a specific database, you can use ALTER DATABASE ... SET.*

Comment: The issue is that it becomes unpredictable. Another issue is that in many cases you need multiple currencies anyway and that makes this data type useless already. USD, EUR, CHF or CAD, it does make a difference and all used on a large scale in businesses. Support for a single currency and a currency that also depends on the database connection, that will cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy using `ALTER DATABASE`. For example:

```
CREATE DATABASE mumble;
ALTER DATABASE mumble SET lc_monetary = 'en_GB.utf8';
```